# Find out which close button closed an alertbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have an alert box with multiple close buttons:

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box cookies-consent">
    <div class="informative-text">
        Using cookies...
    </div>
    <div class="close-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="close sure">Sure</a>
        <a href="#" class="close opt-out">Opt Out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I registered a handler for the close event as the docs suggest:

```
$(document).on('close.fndtn.alert', function(event) {
   console.info('An alert box has been closed!');
   console.info(event);
});
```

But unless I've missed it, the event doesn't seem to indicate which of the buttons was clicked.

How should I modify my HTML/JS to find out which of the close buttons was clicked? I don't want to modify Foundation's own JS, and I do want the UI behavior to remain consistent for both buttons, nice transitions and all.

Comment: You can capture the element that the Click event was triggered on. e.g. this `$('.close').click(function(e){ console.log($(e.target).text()) });` will log the text "Sure" or "Opt Out" to the console, when you click on one of the ".close" classed elements.

Comment: Can't you just use event.target?

Comment: @Panomosh Great! Simple and answers my case perfectly. Please post the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Rich I don't think so - `event.target` in the `close.fndtn.alert` handler is the alertbox itself, not the button which was clicked.

Comment: Or put different id attributes for each button, once clicked you will be able to distinguish by `event.target.id` inside your event callback

Comment: what plugin are  you using?

Comment: @seethrough That doesn't work, it gets the id of the alertbox itself. I'm using the standard Zurb Foundation 5 alertbox.

Comment: is the goal to use `close.fndtn.alert` event specifically? or you are able to bind to `click` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working spinet as @Panomosh mentioned above:

```js
$('a.close').on('click',function(e){
  console.log($(e.target).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-alert class="alert-box cookies-consent">
    <div class="informative-text">
        Using cookies...
    </div>
    <div class="close-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="close sure">Sure</a>
        <a href="#" class="close opt-out">Opt Out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Greetings!

Comment: Clicking on the div outside of the buttons logs both Sure and Opt Out :)